# What is the best way to get Google and Facebook access token for OAuth using React Native?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, access-token, facebook-access-token

I'm getting the profile on server side. Just want the Access token on my frontend.

```
passport.use('google', new GooglePlusTokenStratey ({

clientID: process.env.GCID,
clientSecret: process.env.GCS,


}, async(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
console.log("accessToken ",accessToken);
console.log("refreshToken ",refreshToken);
console.log("profile ",profile);

const existingUser = await Social.findOne({ "uid": profile.id });
if (existingUser) {
  return done(null, existingUser);
}

const newUser = new Social({
    method: "google",
    email: profile.emails[0].value,
    name: profile.displayName,
    uid: profile.id  
  });

  await newUser.save();
  done(null, newUser);

}));
```

I'm calling route now using postman and sending access token in JSON, but want to implement it using react-native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Google Sign In

Use [@react-native-community/google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-community/google-signin).

Common use case:

```js
import { GoogleSignin, statusCodes } from '@react-native-community/google-signin';

// Somewhere in your code
const googleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      const googleUser = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      const accessToken = googleUser.idToken;
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
        console.log('User cancelled google login');
      } else if (e.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
        console.log('Sign in in progress');
      } else if (e.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
        console.log('Play service not available');
      } else {
        console.log('Unknown google sign in error');
      }
    }
  };
```

## Facebook Sign In

Use [react-native-fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk)

Common use case:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { LoginButton, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk';

export default class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <LoginButton
          onLoginFinished={
            (error, result) => {
              if (error) {
                console.log("login has error: " + result.error);
              } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                console.log("login is cancelled.");
              } else {
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                  (data) => {
                    console.log(data.accessToken.toString())
                  }
                )
              }
            }
          }
          onLogoutFinished={() => console.log("logout.")}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: @JunaidAhmed Great that you made it work. Keep going!

Comment: Thank you! this works fine but for expo users see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is correct. However, if you're using expo then you may have to link the packages manually. A better solution for expo users:

### For Google SignIn

Use: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google/

'''

```
import * as Google from 'expo-google-app-auth';

const { type, accessToken, user } = await Google.logInAsync({
  iosClientId: `<YOUR_IOS_CLIENT_ID_FOR_EXPO>`,
  androidClientId: `<YOUR_ANDROID_CLIENT_ID_FOR_EXPO>`,
  iosStandaloneAppClientId: `<YOUR_IOS_CLIENT_ID>`,
  androidStandaloneAppClientId: `<YOUR_ANDROID_CLIENT_ID>`,
});

if (type === 'success') {
  /* `accessToken` is now valid and can be used to get data from the Google API with HTTP requests */
  console.log(user);
}
```

'''

### For Facebook SignIn

Use: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook/

'''

```
async function logIn() {
  try {
    await Facebook.initializeAsync('<APP_ID>');
    const {
      type,
      token,
      expires,
      permissions,
      declinedPermissions,
    } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync({
      permissions: ['public_profile'],
    });
    if (type === 'success') {
      // Get the user's name using Facebook's Graph API
      const response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}`);
      Alert.alert('Logged in!', `Hi ${(await response.json()).name}!`);
    } else {
      // type === 'cancel'
    }
  } catch ({ message }) {
    alert(`Facebook Login Error: ${message}`);
  }
}
```

'''